# creating a custom user database in GAE Java

Tags: java, html, google-app-engine, login-script

This is my first time attempting to make a custom user database. I am trying to make a customer user database in Java in the google app engine - I understand that GAE offers a user openID service, however, this does not work for this application.

Can anyone point me in the direction of somewhere or give me the basics behind designing a custom user database for Java in GAE, how to check people are logged in etc etc? Or any other useful places that will help me on my quest.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at this boilerplate for inspiration: 
https://github.com/davps/Spring3-GAE-boilerplate

---

That said, you don't need to use OpenID with Google's user service. See the available authentication options here:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/#Java_Authentication_options